# What are the wise and allowed ways to add advertisement to iPhone App?

Tags: iphone

I will be publishing an App in a few days. Initially I don't want to add advertisements, but can change my mind anytime, so I've thought this. Add a WebView to application and set its image to a dynamic web content. If no ads; I will display a simple logo, but when ads are available, replace the content with them. So there will be no modification to iPhone compiled binary.

Do you think it is allowed by Apple, and a good approach?

Comment: The best way to get an answer to this question is to specifically ask Apple.  That's the problem with free 'legal' advice, you get what you pay for ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow that approach, you will need to at least explain to Apple when you submit the app for review that ads may be enabled via a webservice.

Apple won't like it if you don't tell them that you might modify the apps feature set or behaviour after its approval.

You should be OK as long as you tell them about it.